# One-step probability transition matrix

Tags: probability, transition-matrix

1. Start by rolling one die
2. If the outcome is even, roll two dice on the next turn
3. If odd, roll one die on the next turn
4. If two dice are rolled and sum is odd, roll one die next turn
5. If two dice are rolled and sum is even, roll two die next turn
6. Game ends, when a sum of 7 or 12 appears.

Write a one-step probability transition matrix for a Markov chain that can describe this situation.

I don't really get how to start on this question. I know the starting probability is 0.5 deciding even/odd.

Comment: Ummm... what *is* the question???  You ought to start by clarifying that.

Comment: I just did, my bad.

Comment: You first think about your state space of the chain. What would that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can identify $3$ states:

1. About to roll one die.$\\[4pt]$

   About to roll two dice.$\\[4pt]$

   Terminal state.

For the above states, the transition matrix is the $3{\times}3$ matrix whose $ij$-th entry $p_{ij}$ is the probability to transition from state $i$ to state $j$ in one turn.

For example
\begin{align*}
p_{11}&=\frac{1}{2}\\[4pt]
p_{23}&=\frac{6}{36}+\frac{1}{36}=\frac{7}{36}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Can you work out the remaining $7$ transition probabilities?

Comment: I am wondering what would the probability of P12 be 1/2 + 29/36? and P13 should be 0 because we can't end the game with just one die. Is this correct?

Comment: @Zac: $p_{13}=0$, but $p_{12}={\large{\frac{1}{2}}}$, not ${\large{\frac{1}{2}}}+{\large{\frac{29}{26}}}$.

Comment: Then similarly, P21=1/2, P22=29/36 P23=7/36

Comment: And P31=P32=P33=7/36?, the terminal state is kind of confusing. If it terminates then the probability of this last row should all be the same?

Comment: @Zac: More care is required. Note that $p_{21},p_{22},p_{23}$ must sum to $1$ (why?).

Comment: @Zac: From the terminal state, we can assume the "next" state is also terminal, hence $$p_{31}=??,\;\;\;p_{32}=??,\;\;\;p_{33}=??$$

Comment: Because pi1+pi2+pi3=1. Then P22=9/36? 1/2+7/36+9/36=1, but I don't get 9/36. Also P31 should be 0 as well.

Comment: @Zac: From state $2$, just work out (a lot more carefully) the count of how many of the $36$ equally likely results transition to each of the $3$ states.

Comment: P31=0 P32=0 P33=1, is this correct?

Comment: @Zac: Yes, your transition probabilities from state $3$ are correct.

Comment: I suppose P21=1/2 P22=11/36 P23=7/36?

Comment: @Zac: $p_{21}$ is not ${\large{\frac{1}{2}}}$ since a sum of $7$ ends the game.

Comment: sorry..i am still a bit confused on state 2. P23 is 7/36, then P21=0? and P22 is 29/36 because the game didn't end and we still have two dice.

Comment: To resolve the confusion, from state $2$, list all $36$ results and for each result, indicate the new state.